# When C++ const methods synchronize mutable state, do non-const methods have to do so too?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

According to Herb Sutter (http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/you-dont-know-const-and-mutable-herb-sutter), in C++11 const methods must not alter the object bit-wise, or must perform internal synchronization (e.g. using a mutex) if they have mutable data members.

My question is, do non-const methods have to acquire the mutex too? Or can they rely on the external synchronization their user will have to perform if the user wants to mix const and non-const methods on the same object concurrently?

EDIT: Put another way,  <strike>is the following class thread-safe?</strike> does the following class provide Sutter's "basic thread safety guarantee" (from [part 4b of GOTW #95](https://herbsutter.com/2014/01/13/gotw-95-solution-thread-safety-and-synchronization/))?

```
#include <thread>

class C {
  public:
  void const_method() const
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
    i = 2;
  }

  void non_const_method()
  {
    // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m); // <-- is this needed?
    i = 1;
  }

  private:
  mutable int i;
  mutable std::mutex m;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your class is not in and of itself thread safe.

```
void non_const_method()
{
    // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m); // <-- is this needed?
    i = 1;
}
```

The above is not thread safe as multiple threads could call the function thus altering `i` at the same time.

So to answer:

> does the following class provide Sutter's "basic thread safety guarantee"

Then yes, the class provides a "basic thread safety guarantee".  You cannot modify one instance from another instance and the `const` methods of the class are thread safe.

You will have to use some sort of external synchronization in order to use the mutable functions of the class on the same instance in multiple threads but your non-mutable function will not require external synchronization.

Comment: How could multiple threads alter `i` at the same time? The only function that can be legally called concurrently is `const_method`, and it acquires a lock. (Code that calls `non_const_method` concurrently wouldn't be thread safe, but there is no such code in the class.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: "*The only function that can be legally called concurrently is const_method,*" And that's why the class is not thread safe. The point Herb is making is that `const` methods should always be thread safe. Non-const methods may or may not be thread safe, depending on the whims of the class implementer. Making `const` methods thread-safe doesn't mean that the entire type is thread-safe (unless the only uses of it use `const` methods).

Comment: @NicolBolas It does mean the entire type is thread-safe, so long as no two non-const methods of the same instance of the class are called at the same time. But then it would be the code that called the two non-const methods at the same time that wasn't thread-safe, not the class. A class is thread safe if it provides predictable behavior when used in multi-threaded code that doesn't violate its interface contract. The usual interface contract is "no concurrent accesses to non-const methods on the same instance". Every class does bad stuff if you violate its interface contract.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: "*A class is thread safe if it provides predictable behavior when used in multi-threaded code that doesn't violate its interface contract.*" I don't think I've ever heard that definition of "thread-safe" before. I'm not sure it's a particularly useful definition, since it basically includes any class which actually has a contract that specifies threading behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's just different words to express the same concept -- adjusted to highlight a relevant point often unstated. Even if you prefer "code that only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time", it's still understood that that is only so long as its interface contract isn't violated. No class ever has to provide "safe execution" if its interface contract is violated, that's the point of interface contracts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz IMHO a class that is thread safe needs no external synchronization on any of its mutable methods(`std::atomic` comes to mind).  This class is exactly like a `std::vector` where only the `const` member function is thread safe.  I think most people would agree that a `std::vector` is not thread safe in and of itself.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: To me, something is "X-safe" if you can use it for X without having to read its interface contract. So a type would be thread safe if you can use it in your threading code and not have to read which functions can or cannot be concurrently called. A class that only provides "safety" if you are very careful with how you use it is not very safe. As an analogy, C4 is a safe explosive because it only blows up when you want it to. Nitro glycerine by contrast is not considered safe, even though it won't blow up if you are very careful about handling it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Every class will fail if you don't follow its interface contract. You can't use any class for anything safely without understanding its interface contract. Your proposed definition of thread safe is not good one. For example, consider a queue that provides an `isEmpty` function and a `get` function that crashes if you call it on an empty queue (and no other query/get type functions). If there are no restrictions on concurrent invocation, is that class thread safe? (Perhaps a more accurate definition is that a class is thread safe if it provides useful concurrency?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: "*Every class will fail if you don't follow its interface contract.*" And a safe class is one where the contract *cannot* be broken (without employing perfidy). Your example fails because `get` is not a safe function; it crashes for reasons that you cannot control or prevent. In a thread-safe class, it would throw or otherwise error on failure, not crash.

Comment: @NicolBolas Almost every class of any significance is not "safe" by this definition, and most such classes would be impractically clunky. Is a container thread-safe if modifications invalidate iterators? Would you argue that a thread-safe container that owns its objects cannot return a reference to an object in it?

Comment: I think my "put another way" didn't actually rephrase my question, it asked a different one, so I'm going to edit the question for clarity. I did find another Sutter article that was helpful: https://herbsutter.com/2014/01/13/gotw-95-solution-thread-safety-and-synchronization/. In different parts of it, he effectively defines "thread-safe type" to mean the same as a fully internally synchronized type, like a message queue. Elsewhere, he defines "basic thread safety guarantee" to mean "concurrent operations on different objects is safe; concurrent const operations on the same object is safe".

Comment: @SCFrench Yes I was not understanding exactly what you were asking.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, a *writer* needs to obtain more strict lock than a *reader* would. You might have argued if reader need to obtain a lock or not (but you asked the other way). Writers are more of the cause to produce data inconsistency.

By strict lock, I mean in a locking-protocol where reader-lock and writer-lock are possible - then writer-lock would be more strict. In most implementations, a thread which obtained a writer-lock would stall all other threads from obtaining any kind of lock, but reader-locks can be taken simultaneously. So, a non-const function would ideally take a writer-lock, but `const` function may simply take a reader-lock - thus allowing parallel execution of same function (or similar `const` functions of same object).

Yes, it is possible that a locking-protocol won't give preference to *writer* threads waiting, over *reader* thread waiting. But, that's implementation detail.